# Google Contacts API : RetrivePhoto query failed - invalid contact ID

Tags: php, google-contacts-api, google-client

I am trying to retrieve the photo of a contact using Google Contacts API according to [this document](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_a_contacts_photo). The PHP Client library used is [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/master/src/Google). I get the code and user information successfully but failed to get the user's photo data.

The response I got is :

> Photo query failed - invalid contact ID

.

This is the PHP code of the callback function that I'm using to get the user's photo data :

```
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setClientId(GOOGLE_APP_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_APP_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setRedirectUri(GOOGLE_APP_CLIENT_REDIRECT_URI);
$client->addScope("openid profile email https://www.google.com/m8/feeds");

// Create a OAuth 2 service instance
$oauth2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);

// Get the access token using code.
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    // Authenticate the code
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['access_code'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    
    // Set the access token
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    $temp_obj = $client->verifyIdToken();
    ....
    // Get the user's info
    $guser_info = $oauth2->userinfo->get();
    // Get the contact id
    $contact_id = $guser_info['id'];
    // Get the user email
    $user_email = $guser_info['email'];
    
    // Make an authenticated request to the photo
    $req = new Google_Http_Request("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/default/$contact_id");
    // For replacing above line with the following also got the same result.
    //$req = new Google_Http_Request("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/$user_email/$contact_id");
    
    // Make an authenticated request
    $val = $client->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($req);
    
    print_r($val->getResponseBody());// Get "Photo query failed - invalid contact ID"
} ...
```

I have enabled `Contacts API` in the console project and added scope `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds`.

Is the retrieved ***id*** different from *Contact ID* of the user or is there a way to get the user's *Contact ID* or something wrong in my code?
Any help or comments are appreciated.

Comment: The logic in the code is wrong. It is trying to retrieve the photo of the current user by retrieving details of the current user from current user's contact list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [Hybridauth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) with a similar code to get the user profile image ([laravel](http://laravel.com/) style):

```
<?php
//@see http://www.mrcasual.com/on/coding/laravel4-package-management-with-composer/
public function getSocial($action = '')
{
    // check URL segment
    if ($action == 'auth') {
        // process authentication
        try {
            Hybrid_Endpoint::process();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            // redirect back to http://URL/social/
            return Redirect::to('login/social');
        }
        return;
    }
    try {
        // create a HybridAuth object
        $socialAuth = new Hybrid_Auth(app_path() . '/config/hybridauth.php');
        // authenticate with provider
        if($action != ''){
            if(in_array($action,array('google'))){
                $provider = $socialAuth->authenticate($action);
            }else{
                return Redirect::to('login');
            }
        }else{
            return Redirect::to('login');
        }
        // fetch user profile
        $userProfile = $provider->getUserProfile();
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        // exception codes can be found on HybBridAuth's web site
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
    access user profile data
    echo "Connected with: <b>{$provider->id}</b><br />";
    echo "As: <b>{$userProfile->displayName}</b><br />";
    echo "<pre>" . print_r( $userProfile, true ) . "</pre><br />";
    echo "PhotoURL: {$userProfile->photoUrl}<br />";
    die();
}
```

Maybe your `$guser_info` already contains a link to the photo? Did you try to `print_r` it?

Comment: Yes. I can get the photo URL from $user_info. And the error is due to the logic.